# Problem in calling Python script from PHP

Tags: php, python

This is my python script which creates a "test.txt" file when executed. when I execute using terminal (Ubuntu 11.04) `root@gml-VirtualBox:/var/www/HMS# python test.py`. It creates the "test.txt" in the `/var/www/HMS` directory as I expected.

```
test.py:

#!/usr/bin/env python

def init():
    filename = "test.txt"
    file = open(filename, 'w')
    file.write("This is the new content of test.txt :-)")
    file.close()
    print "done"

def main():
    init()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But when I try to call this test.py using PHP, It's not creating the 'test.txt' output file.

```
index.php:

$tmp = exec("python test.py");
echo "temp: $tmp";
```

Both `test.py` & `index.php` are in the same directory(`/var/www/HMS/`). But when I modified the `test.py` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def init():
    print "done"

def main():
    init()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It prints `temp: done` in the browser, which is what I expected.

I don't know why my previous python code didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you test the python script on the command line, you're running as `root`. Chances are you're not running the webserver as `root` (which is a good thing), and the webserver's user does not have appropriate permissions to create and/or write to that file.

Comment: thanks alot for your answer Mat..Now I fixed that. However I have similar problem when executing `nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()` function. This time permission is not an issue, as I checked that after your suggestion. If you are familiar with `NLTK library`, can he help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6646310/585329)

Comment: How did you set permissions for webserver?

Comment: A lot of shared server providers won't allow to use `exec()`. So you're python script will never be called at all this way.